# SELECT id of affected row after MERGE sql

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I was using a simple approach to updating data in a SQL Server 2008 R2, which required 2 queries and some logic. Basically, `SELECT` query, if match found `UPDATE` query, else `INSERT` query.

When I did insert, I used `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id;` to get the id of the row, when I did update, I already had the id from the `SELECT` query. THEN I converted all the above to an elegant `MERGE` Query. And there went the id of the affected row, scope_identity no longer works.

How would I be able to get the id of either the inserted, or updated row from a `MERGE` query.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: apologies, edited post. I'm using MSSQL 2008R2 server by the way.

Comment: Have a look at the `OUTPUT` clause on `MERGE`. It also applies to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.